# Two different delta values in a quadratic equation

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics

I have an equation $5x^2+5x+1=0$ to solve in field $Z_{11}$.

$\Delta = 5$ and so when we arrive to deriving the final solutions, we must take the square root. The problem is that:

$$4^2 = 16 \equiv 5 (\mod 11)$$
$$7^2 = 49 \equiv 5 (\mod 11)$$

And so we may very well say that $\sqrt{\Delta}$ is either 4 or 7, right? What to do then? Do I calculate for both values and thus get more than two solutions?

Comment: Since $7\equiv -4 \pmod{11}$, you found both the positive and negative square root.

Comment: @JohnHabert - Yes, but also $4 \equiv -7 (\mod 11)$ so which one do I use if I want to just find the solutions using the regular $\frac{-b +- \sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}$?

Comment: You use both since you call one $+\sqrt{\Delta}$ and you call the other $-\sqrt{\Delta}$. And I removed my previous comment once I saw the correction in your comment.

Comment: @JohnHabert - oh, ok. In the example above, I end up with the same solutions (2/10 which is not in $Z_{11}$ and 1 which is) whichever delta value I choose. Does that mean I can always choose either one in such case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the discussion in the comments, it appears that the problem here is less with $\sqrt{\Delta}$ and more with the modular arithmetic. Since $4^2 \equiv 7^2 \equiv 5 \pmod{11}$ and $\pm4\equiv \mp7 \pmod{11}$, we have found both square roots of $5 \pmod{11}$. Now using the quadratic formula, we have $x = \dfrac{-b \pm\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a} = \dfrac{-5\pm\sqrt{5}}{10}$. At this point, we can replace $\sqrt{5}$ with either $4$ or $7$ and evaluate the two solutions. The trick here is that this is all happen in $\Bbb{Z}_{11}$. So $\dfrac{-5\pm\sqrt{5}}{10}$ can be rewritten as $\dfrac{-5\pm\sqrt{5}}{-1}$ since $10\equiv -1 \pmod{11}$. This yields the two solutions of $1$ and $9$.

Comment: That's exactly what I didn't get, thank you a lot! :)

Comment: You're welcome. It helps that you tried the problem before asking questions and answered questions with what you did and where you got stuck.